# MockBean doesn't return proper value

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I'm writing Spring application to familiarize myself with messaging part of the framework. I want to send events requesting the server to roll a die. I am able to spawn listeners listening to different queues during runtime. This controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class JmsController {
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
private DiceRollingService diceRollingService;

@Autowired
public JmsController(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DiceRollingService diceRollingService) {
    this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    this.diceRollingService = diceRollingService;
}

@PostMapping("/createQueue")
public void createQueue(@RequestParam String name) throws JMSException {
    Session session = connectionFactory.createConnection().createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Queue queue = session.createQueue(name);
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
    consumer.setMessageListener(new CustomListener(name, diceRollingService));
}

@PostMapping("/sendToQueue")
public void sendToQueue(@RequestBody EventRoll event) {
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(event.getTargetQueue(), event);
}
}
```

One endpoint is responsible for creating new consumer, and another one allows to send a message to it. Below is code for my listener.

```
public class CustomListener implements MessageListener {
private final String queueName;
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
private final DiceRollingService diceRollingService;

public CustomListener(String queueName, DiceRollingService diceRollingService) {
    this.queueName = queueName;
    objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    this.diceRollingService = diceRollingService;
}

@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        String messageBody = message.getBody(String.class);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(messageBody);
        EventType type = EventType.valueOf(json.getString("eventType"));

        switch(type) {
            case ROLL:
                EventRoll event = objectMapper.readValue(messageBody, EventRoll.class);
                int a = diceRollingService.rollDice(event.getDie());
                System.out.println("Rolled: " + a + " from " + event.getDie() + " die at " + queueName);
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Currently I am able to receive only one event called EventRoll which has following fields: targetQueue(used in controller), eventType(used in listener) and die(used in service). Mentioned service is responsible for rolling a die:

```
@Service
public class DiceRollingService {
private final SecureRandom generator;

public DiceRollingService() {
    generator = new SecureRandom();
}

public int rollDice(Integer dice) {
    return generator.nextInt(dice) + 1;
}
}
```

For a few days I was testing everything manually using Postman. I was making requests to create queue's and then sending EventRoll's to them. That was working fine, but I decided to write some automated unit tests. I have come up with something like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class EventRollTest {
@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
@MockBean
private DiceRollingService diceRollingService;
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Test
public void eventRollReceived() throws Exception {
    when(diceRollingService.rollDice(any())).thenReturn(5);

    JmsController jmsController = new JmsController(jmsTemplate, connectionFactory, diceRollingService);
    jmsController.createQueue("newQueue");
    EventRoll eventRoll = new EventRoll(10);
    eventRoll.setEventType(EventType.ROLL);
    eventRoll.setTargetQueue("newQueue");
    jmsController.sendToQueue(eventRoll);

    verify(diceRollingService, times(1)).rollDice(any());
}
}
```

Here comes the problem. It seems like dicerollingService mock doesn't return proper value. The output i get is:

> Rolled: 0 from 10 die at newQueue

> Wanted but not invoked:
> diceRollingService bean.rollDice();
> -> events.EventRollTest.eventRollReceived(EventRollTest.java:38)
> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Verify method suggests that this mock isn't even used. So far I changed my controller to use constructor injection, to pass mocked service from test during instancing. When I call this mock directly from test, or from JmsController it behaves as intended. Only in CustomListener something seems to not function properly. When I change the annotation from @MockBean to @Mock, it returns proper value, but verify methos still claims there were no interactions with the object. I suspect the proper comes from CustomListener not being a Spring bean. Do you have any suggestions how is it possible to fix architecture and/or test so that it actually will work?

Comment: If your `CustomListener` isn't a Spring Bean, where/how does it get the dependencies from? How is this thing being created? There is too little information currently to go on.

Comment: It is created in method createQueue in JmsController, where it obtains diceRollingService instance, as shown in top-most snippet.

Comment: Well the method is called as you are getting the output, you are injecting the mock. So it doesn't match. What does your `EventRoll` look like?